# Wronskian zero with linearly independent solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Any ideas how to go about proving this?

Functions $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ are linearly independent on the interval $[\alpha,\beta]$, but their Wronskian $W(\phi,\psi)=0$ for some $x\in [\alpha, \beta]$.

Prove that exist at least two points $x_1,x_2 \in [\alpha, \beta]$ such that $\phi(x_1)=\psi′(x_2)=0$.

I've naturally started with considering the point at which the Wronskian vanishes, say $\phi(x_0)\psi'(x_0)-\phi'(x_0)\psi(x_0)=0$ and then took them to each side and arrive at the logs being equal when evaluated at x0 but I'm not sure if this makes sense and if it doesn, where to go from there?

I'm not sure how the linear independence comes in to play? Should I'm be attempting this at a higher level rather than constructively?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You tag DE, but where is the equation?

Comment: Yes, but it's just a general question for any given D.E.

Answer (score 3):

That's wrong. Consider $\phi(x) = x^2 + 10$ and $\psi(x) = \cos x+ 10$ on $[0,1]$. Then $\phi$ and $\psi$ are linearly independent, $\psi$ does not vanish on $[0,1]$, but 
$$ W(\phi, \psi)(0) = \phi(0)\psi'(0) - \phi'(0)\psi(0) = 10 \cdot 0 - 0 \cdot 10 = 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you left some important information out (since you've given it the differential equations tag), namely, that $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ are two linearly independent solutions of the same second order differential equation.

If that's indeed correct, all you have to do is look up Sturm's Separation Theorem, that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sturm's Separation Theorem seems to be going on the right track but I still can't really understand it.
The theorem talks about an open interval whereas I have a closed interval and also it mentions roots whereas I don't have any involved as far as I know.

Could you explain just a little more, thanks!

Comment: Let's assume your second order differential equation has homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions. First, try to sketch what a nontrivial solution *without* any zeroes on the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$ would look like. Then, sketch another function obeying the boundary conditions, which has exactly one zero somewhere in the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$. Now, realise that you have to show that of the two linearly independent solutions you're given ($\phi$ and $\psi$), one of them is zero somewhere in the interval, while the other has a local extremum somewhere (else) in the interval...

Comment: ... Since those solutions are continuously differentiable, try to see from your sketch what Sturm's Separation Theorem tells about the number of roots of one solution, and how that implies something about the number of local extrema of the other solution.

Comment: Also, it would help quite a bit if you could edit your question to make it more self-contained, i.e. add the entire statement and context of the problem. At this stage, I'm answering the question I assume you want answered, which is a bit of a long stretch.